# Getting java.lang.nullpointer exception while calling feature file

Tags: karate

I just simply tried call feature file inside another feature file, but keep on am getting java.lang.nullpointer exception.

I have various techniques and methods which are provided karate official blog but still the error is same.

```
Feature: Quote generator

Background:
* url 'https://reqres.in'


@SmokeTest
Scenario: Fetch random quote

Given path '/api/users/'+pageNo.Pageno
When method GET
Then status 200
* def Response = response.data
Then print 'Value of response is: ' +Response
Then def msg = call read('file:src/test/java/com/features/Generic.feature') {name:'lakshmi', job:'Software'}
```

---

```
Feature: Generic scenarios

Scenario: pass logs into test execution report
* def json = {name: '#(name)', job: '#(job)'}
* print json

Given path '/api/users'
And request json
When method Post
Then status 201
```

Actual Error which am getting:

Then def msg = call read('file:src/test/java/com/features/Generic.feature') {name:'lakshmi', job:'Software'} # StepDefs.def(String,String)
      java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateHtmlReporter.karateStepProceed(KarateHtmlReporter.java:180)
       at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateReporterBase.karateStep(KarateReporterBase.java:79)
       at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateReporterBase.callBegin(KarateReporterBase.java:69)
       at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFeatureCall(Script.java:1657)
       at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFeatureCall(Script.java:1641)
       at com.intuit.karate.Script.call(Script.java:1578)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
* def calledFeature = call read('classpath:com/features/Generic.feature')  {name:'lakshmi', job:'Software'}
```

See here:

```
Prefix     | Description
classpath: | relative to the classpath, recommended for re-usable features
file:      | do not use this unless you know what you are doing, see above
this:      | when in a called feature, ensure that files are resolved relative to the current feature file
```

This can be found here in the documentation : https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files